# How do I create a make file in windows operating system and run it using cmd

Tags: c++, c

I am new to makefile concept
so to try out if I am able to run and compile c files using word "make"in command prompt I made   main.c (which contains main function)  ,ttt.c   (which contain a function void ttt(int)) ,  mandar.h  (headerfile to include void ttt(int) function in main.c)
when I run this program in cmd using "gcc main.c ttt.c -o main && main",program gets compiled and run properly(so there shouldn't be any error in code)

Now in the same directory I made a file Makefile.txt as follow 
[image of makefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymHPw.png)

Now when I type "make "in cmd following message is shown
[image of cmd message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVwLt.png)

I typed everything exactly the same way as in "head first c " book
did I miss something 
this is my first time to ask a question so suggestion regarding improvement of questions are also welcomed

Comment: Either get a linux-like environment such as Cygwin or get Visual Studio and use nmake. Google it.

Comment: can't i do it in windows cmd because till now i done everything including java c , c++ and python in cmd...so i am quite comfortable with windows cmd

Comment: Well Windows doesn't have a built-in `make` functionality. So you can use `nmake`, provided by Visual Studio.

Comment: ok.... so i had to use just "namake" in place of "make " in visual studio command line and it would work fine...is it right?

Comment: 1) `Makefile.txt` --> `makefile` 2) add `all: mandar.exe` to first. and change to `mandar.exe: ttt.o main.o`

Comment: +BLUEPIXY  i added your suggested edits but still no change in result

Comment: DeiDei..i tried MSBuild command prompt for vs2015 and Developer command prompt for vs2015 but result is still same

Comment: Do you do comment (1)? rename Makefile.txt makefile.

Comment: BLUEPIXY yes ...but it makes makefile to makefile.txt by default...so to cut default what etention i should add ..it makes every file text document if no extention is added

Comment: do `rename Makefile.txt makefile` on command prompt .

Comment: or `make -f Makefile.txt`

Comment: BLUEPIXY it worked thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not `Makefile.txt`, you have to name it without any extension just `Makefile`.
Then run the command.

FIY make by default searches for `Makefile` in the current working directory. You can change this default behavior by typing `make -f filename` into the command prompt.

Comment: thanks its working...initially i tried to rename but by notpad was giving it defaut type txt when i done he same from cmd it worked

Answer (score 1):

You create your `Makefile` with some editor (`emacs`, `vim`, perhaps `notepad`). Beware that tab characters are *significant* in that `Makefile` and most "action" lines in it should start with a tab, not several spaces.

You then type `make` in some terminal or command window.

Comment: Could even use wordpad

Comment: yes i am aware of that  and thanks for advice...do you have any suggestion regarding why cmd shows message "no makefile found"